# Getting all bazaar (bzr) branch list with bzr command

Tags: version-control, bazaar

Is there any way to get all bazaar branches from remote shared repository?

I found it can be with Bazaar Explorer, but could not find which be **with bzr command**.

- In Git: `git branches -r`.
- In Subversion, `svn ls <REPOSITORY_ROOT>/branches`.

How about in bazaar?

I think it is very important to find what branches are in the repository, and I believe bzr must support that feature easily, but I could not find the way by searching the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `bzr heads` should do what you need (it's part of the `bzrtools` plugin, which should be part of the standard distribution).

Note that `bzr heads` will not show branches in different directories as different if they are identical. It checks the DAG of the repository structure, not the directory layout.

Comment: `bzr heads --tips bzr://bzr.sv.gnu.org/emacs` showed branches.
But an elapsed time was `real    10m44.473s, user    0m4.716s, sys     0m1.170s`.
It's too late (because it scans a repository structure, I think) to just find branches.
Bazaar Explorer is also late.
Best practice to find branches is to use a web interface such as loggerhead, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that Bazaar loads and analyzes the repository DAG rather than scanning the directory structure. In principle, little more than `find * -name .bzr -exec dirname '{}' ';'` is necessary to find all the branches. The `bzr trees` command does the equivalent, but only works with local repositories.

Comment: I heard that bzrtools is discontinued and do not work with newer version of bazaar.